# flux TCA db group

Tags: typo3, flux

I would like to know how this:

```
<flux:flexform.field.group name="abc" label="abc" internalType="db" allowed="pages" maxItems="1" minItems="0" size="1" displayCond="FIELD:settings.typ.choose:=:4" />
```

would look in FLUX 7.1.2

I tried with *relations* and *wizard* and *inline* but it never did what I would have liked. All I can find while searching is that I have to use *relation* but never how to use it. [This didn't help either](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/flux/master/Field/RelationViewHelper.html)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your given example should roughly match this one:

```
<flux:field.relation maxItems="1" minItems="0"
                     size="1" displayCond="FIELD:settings.typ.choose:=:4"
                     table="pages" name="abc" label="abc">
    <flux:wizard.list table="pages" />
</flux:field.relation>
```

Comment: But the wizard only lists the child pages not the whole page tree